# TCP input data packets are combined in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a simple TCP client in dart:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  const sendData = "\$I,Z,0.5,5,0*\r\n";

  final socket = Socket.connect("192.168.1.100", int.parse("8008"))
      .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5))
      .whenComplete(() {
    print("Connected!");
  }).catchError((_) {
    print("Error!");
  });
  socket.then((soc) {
    soc.write(sendData);
    soc.listen((data) {
      print(String.fromCharCodes(data).trim);
    });
  });
}
```

This program sends a special message to server and after that, the server sends back a bunch of data **every 10 ms**. The output is as follows:

```
$I,1,250,0,206*$I,1,248,0,192*$I,1,246,0,178*$I,1,245,0,165*
$I,1,244,0,153*$I,1,244,0,141*$I,1,244,0,131*$I,1,245,0,121*
$I,1,246,0,113*$I,1,248,0,105*$I,1,250,0,98*
$I,1,253,0,92*$I,2,0,0,86*$I,2,4,0,82*$I,2,8,0,79*$I,2,12,0,76*
$I,2,18,0,74*$I,2,23,0,74*$I,2,29,0,74*$I,2,36,0,75*$I,2,42,0,77*$I,2,50,0,80*$I,2,58,0,84*$I,2,66,0,89*$I,2,74,0,94*
$I,2,83,0,101*$I,2,93,0,109*$I,2,103,0,117*$I,2,113,0,126*$I,2,124,0,136*$I,2,134,0,147*
$I,2,146,0,159*$I,2,157,0,171*$I,2,169,0,185*$I,2,182,0,199*$I,2,194,0,214*$I,2,207,0,230*$I,2,220,0,246*$I,2,233,1,8*$I,2,247,1,26*$I,3,5,1,44*$I,3,19,1,64*$I,3,33,1,84*
$I,3,48,1,105*$I,3,63,1,126*$I,3,77,1,148*$I,3,93,1,171*$I,3,108,1,194*$I,3,123,1,217*
$I,3,138,1,242*$I,3,154,2,10*$I,3,169,2,35*$I,3,185,2,61*$I,3,201,2,87*$I,3,216,2,113*$I,3,232,2,140*$I,3,248,2,167*$I,4,7,2,195*
$I,4,23,2,223*$I,4,39,2,251*$I,4,54,3,23*$I,4,70,3,51*
```

The server sends data in **$I,1,250,0,206*** format, i.e. starts with $ and ends with *. As one may note, several consecutive data packages are concatenated incorrectly. 
Whenever I increase the interval, for example to 200 ms, everything is ok.

What should I do?

**UPDATE**

Besides the BrettSutton answer which is true, the contributers in dart github gave a more complete answer [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40228).

I decided to parse the packet in Socket listen handler, split that and append it to a list. As I want to show the data on a chart, I reset the list after 100 data. However the data could be logged as well.

```
soc.listen((data) {
  var av = data.length;
  if (av != 0) {
    var stList = String.fromCharCodes(data).trim().split("\$");
    stList.forEach((str) {
      if (str.isNotEmpty) {
        var strS = str.split(",");
        if (strS != null) y = parseData(strS);
        sampleList.add(y);
      }
    });
    print(sampleList);
    if (sampleList.length > 100) {
      sampleList.clear();
    }
    print("==========");
  }
});
```

Comment: TCP is a simple byte stream, it is up to you to pull out the messages from the byte stream. I used to have a method called something like readMesage that read the byte stream until a full message was read. TCP will clump the bytes into packets. A packet may contain a single message , part of a message or parts of multiple messages.You must deal with all these combos.

Comment: @BrettSutton Thanks!  checked the data. Nothing is missed. Only some packets are merged as a single one, as you  said. I should create a map with data index and data because the data order is very important for me.

Comment: the default dart map is a linked map which means that you can iterate over the map in the order you inserted the elements. However not certain why you would use a map over a list. Depending how your client consumes the data you may want to look at using a stream. When you receive data you insert it into a stream. You can then setup code elsewhere in your dart client to listen to that stream.

Comment: @BrettSutton My app should get data over TCP and draw a semi-realtime chart. So the order and integrity of data is important. I should keep the order in some way. The stream idea s nice.  would try to implement that. Thanks.